# How can i handle this async function properly?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, soap, promise, async-await

I'm in a project which is using a SOAP API. I'm using the soap npm package. I'm using `soap.createClientAsync` function to create my connection with the wsdlURL. When I try to acces the methods in the client I get `undefined`. I have tried this solutions but couldnt get anywhere.

****First aproach****

```
  public async getProducts() {
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL);
    console.log(client.Add(args));
  }
```

This is the error log:

```
undefined
callback(error, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest)
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

****Second aproach****, its exactly as how the documentation demostrates on how to use async.

```
 public async getProducts() {
    soap
      .createClientAsync(wsdlURL)
      .then((client) => {
        console.log(client.Add(args));
        return client.Add(args);
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

And it logs exactly the same as the first approach

```
undefined
callback(error, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest)
TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Any suggestions on how can I access my client functions and then return the value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution, this is what i did:

```
  public async getProducts() {
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlURL);
    client.Add(args, (err, result, body) => {
      const res = result;
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```